# How identify an AMR file with PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to get the mimeType of audio files. For `.amr` file, all I can get is `application/octet-stream`.
 I know it means apache server couldn't guess the mimetype, because nothing seems to be related in `magic.mime` file. I tried  every mimeType of php and symfony, but since it's an issue with apache server, i don't know what to do
Any advice ?

Comment: Why don't you just check the extension yourself and return the MIME type that you think it should be?

Comment: The extension can lie, an image without extension still is an image.

Comment: As @esdebon says, you can't trust files extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can identify the file type with the first characters in the file, an arm file say #!AMR

[image]

or you can try something like this:

```
echo getImageMimeType(file_get_contents ("yourFile.amr"));

function getBytesFromHexString($hexdata)
{
  for($count = 0; $count < strlen($hexdata); $count+=2)
    $bytes[] = chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $count, 2)));

  return implode($bytes);
}

function getImageMimeType($imagedata)
{
  $imagemimetypes = array(
    "jpeg" => "FFD8", 
    "png" => "89504E470D0A1A0A", 
    "gif" => "474946",
    "bmp" => "424D", 
    "tiff" => "4949",
    "tiff" => "4D4D"
  );

  foreach ($imagemimetypes as $mime => $hexbytes)
  {
    $bytes = getBytesFromHexString($hexbytes);
    if (@substr($imagedata, 0, strlen($bytes)) == $bytes)
      return $mime;
  }

  /// This is to get the hexa char of amr
  echo $bytes;

  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The first bits are indeed `#!AMR`, that could do the trick. Is there a list of all first bits by extension? Thanks !

Comment: This is not a secure method for validating the content type of uploaded files.

Comment: @symcbean please tell me why

Comment: Hey @symcbean - could you please explain why this is not a secure method? I am left with no option since PHP magic.mime file does not have .amr information. I am looking for a secure method and landed here!

Comment: Because its does not check the content type - it just looks for some magic numbers. Put this on your webserver and, if the webserver config is not exactly right there is an easy exploit by embedding PHP code. It allows any warez or kiddie Pr0n to be uploaded just be prefixing it with the right bytes. If you want "secure" you need to parse/verify  the entire file **and** run a malware scan against it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to serve static files with Apache - in which case this question has got nothing to do with PHP. You just need to [tell the webserver](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) to return a mime type of audio/AMR for files with a .AMR extension.

I don't know what you've tried with PHP, but it's not hard:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: audio/AMR");
print file_get_contents("afile.amr");
```

Comment: Sorry I can't rely on the extension to get the mimetype. you can hide the extension with another.

Comment: If you don't control the filenames on your server you don't control your server. If you are trying to determine the content of files arriving from outside your server - this is NOT stated in your question and the method proposed by esdebon is insecure.

Comment: I'm restrincting/checking the extension sent by users in the front-end (angular) and checking again with php. But was unable to do it with .amr file. Why esdebon method is insecure ?

Comment: Because it is easy to subvert to use your site for distributing any kind of file, and if your only check is to look at the file extension and the first few bytes of your file, anyone with upload privileges can run their own code on your server.

Comment: Ok, then the code is secure. The problem is have a unsafe .htaccess file.